# How do you drop items in a list that's created through a loop?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following lines of code:

```
randomnumbers = {10};
For[w = 1, w <= 10, w++,
 randomnumbers = Append[randomnumbers, RandomInteger[10]];
 addition = Last[randomnumbers] + Last[Drop[randomnumbers, -1]];
 
 
 Print[randomnumbers];
 Print[addition]
 ]
```

Basically, I have a list given by `randomnumbers`where the first number is 10.  Every iteration of the loop adds a random integer between 0 - 10 to `randomnumbers`. Once that number is added, I then do addition and I add the newly appended number to the number immediately before it.  The issue is that every time the loop runs, `randomnumbers`stores all the previously added values.  What I would like to do is that once `addition`is performed, the number in position 1 of `randomnumbers` is dropped.  That way at any one time, there are only a max of two numbers in the list made by `randomnumbers` the newly appended number and the one immediately before it.

As it currently runs the outputs look something like this:

```
{10,1}
11
{10,1,2}
3
{10,1,2,5}
7
etc
```

but I would like an output that runs like what I've written below, where the list is not continuously increasing.

```
{10,1}
11
{1,2}
3
{2,5}
7
etc
```

I have tried adding in `Drop[randomnumbers,1]`after addition, but that doesn't seem to continuously remove the number in position 1 of `randomnumbers`

Comment: Have you tried `randomnumbers  = Drop[randomnumbers,1]`?

Answer (score 3):

```
randomnumbers = {10};
For[w = 1, w <= 10, w++,
 randomnumbers = {Last[randomnumbers], RandomInteger[10]};
 addition = Total[randomnumbers];
 Print[randomnumbers];
 Print[addition]]
```

Comment: Wow, that's neat!

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is this one:

```
randomnumbers = {10};
For[w = 1, w <= 10, w++,
 If[w > 1, randomnumbers = Drop[randomnumbers, 1];
  randomnumbers = Append[randomnumbers, RandomInteger[10]];, 
  randomnumbers = Append[randomnumbers, RandomInteger[10]];];
 addition = Last[randomnumbers] + Last[Drop[randomnumbers, -1]];
 Print[randomnumbers]; Print[addition]]
```

P.S. I don't know yet how to properly write a code as an answer, I apologize for that, it is my second day using StackExchange forums.

Answer (score 0):

Note you could this with [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html), e.g.

```
fun[n_] := 
 With[{s = Rest[NestList[{#[[2]], RandomInteger[10]} &, {0, 10}, n]]},
  Thread[{s, Total /@ s}]]
```

A list of 10 `fun[10]`:

> {{{10, 0}, 10}, {{0, 7}, 7}, {{7, 6}, 13}, {{6, 1}, 7}, {{1, 7},
> 8}, {{7, 6}, 13}, {{6, 6}, 12}, {{6, 10}, 16}, {{10, 10},    20},
> {{10, 3}, 13}}